# Use StreamSocket class to get http response from IIS application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, httponly, cookie-httponly

My goal is to try to get the httponly cookie to be able to get the background transfer service to process my requests on wp8.

An approach i have taken from [How can I get HttpOnly cookies in Windows Phone 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16290773/how-can-i-get-httponly-cookies-in-windows-phone-8) was to create a StreamSocket instance and read raw data.

Apart from an unfortunate 'it doesnt work through proxy', which i can leave with, i have faced another issue - my application in IIS runs under the main site (e.g. https://supersite.com/myapp).

Is there any way i could use StreamSocket to make requests to IIS application, not just the host name?